# How do you adjust for elevation and layers not sticking together?

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design

My printer was working fine two weeks ago, I traveled cross country with it (making sure it was secure while moving) to a place of significantly lower elevation. Nothing has printed well since I got here, including the print I did two weeks ago (same settings). I've adjusted flow rate, extruder temperature, infill density and style, fan settings, and releveled the bed, and I still have really brittle layers that don't hold together. It's almost like the nozzle is moving up and down on each layer in a pattern.

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! An image of your printed objects would help a lot.

Comment: What type of bed do you have ?

Comment: What material are you printing?  Do you have a printer model?

Comment: Are the thermistors measuring temperature correctly.